# Administrator password after restoring registry

Tags: windows-xp, password-recovery

I had some problem during system boot. I read that this problem can be solved by registry replace using:

```
copy c:\windows\repair\system c:\windows\system32\config\system
copy c:\windows\repair\software c:\windows\system32\config\software
copy c:\windows\repair\sam c:\windows\system32\config\sam
copy c:\windows\repair\security c:\windows\system32\config\security
copy c:\windows\repair\default c:\windows\system32\config\default
```

Unfortunately system still won't boot properly. Now I can't access the recovery console, because administrator password is required (and it isn't empty). Is there any default admin password stored in registry from repair directory?

Answer (score 1):

The best to do this job is the tool created by Petter Nordhal-Haggen:

[Off Line NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)

All the instructions on the web site.